# How to spot elements belonging to the same row using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a table that contains multiple rows and columns.

I need to locate an element in column one that lies in the same row with a particular element in colum two.

Here is  apart of HTML

```
<tr>
<td element1>
</td>
<td element2>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td element3>
</td>
<td element4>
</td>
</tr>
```

Elements: element1 and element3 have absolutely the same HTML. **The only thing that I can use to differentiate between them is their sibling elements: element3 and element4.**

**I need to locate element3 BECAUSE it is a sibling of element 4. So first I need to narrow down my search to element that are in the same row `<tr` as element4. Then, I can locate element3. How can I do this?**

PS: I cannot use `.get(2)` or tr[2] ... etc. But I can navigate element2 and element 4 individually

Comment: Have you looked into XPath? I'm not 100% on what you're asking, but you say they have the exact same HTML - XPath is perfect for that. It locates off of location, not any other markers. If the HTML is bad enough, you can start from <html> and say go past 2 div's, go into the img and hit the first whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pieces of code should work:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table tr > td"));
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size; i++){
    if (elements[i].getAttribute("attribute that will identify element 4").equals("something")){
       elements[i-1].performAction();
}
```

Alternatively, the better way is to use an XPath selector.  I generally don't like XPath, but this is a case where I would use it.

Because I don't know the special selector to get the element, here's how "previous sibling works" on XPath:

```
//E/preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

Where E is the selector to get to the element.

Answer (score 5):

In Selenium 2, you are able to select using the following CSS Selectors

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table tr:nth-child(X) > td:nth-child(X)"));
```

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find examples? I can't quite get it how to implement it in my case

Comment: fiddle with the `X` that i have in there.  If you wanted to select the second `td` under the second `tr`, then you'd use `table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)`  play around with the numbers. you'll get it.

Comment: This is not exactly what i need. I do not know that my element is located in the 2nd row. **The only thing I know is that my element is located in the same row as element4** i cannot use row 2 column 2 etc